# how to fetch latest n messages using imap

Tags: smtp, imap

I want to fetch messages from icloud mail using imap when using **imap.seq.fetch('1:n', fetchOptions)** its fetching first n messages, but I want to fetch from the recent order. How can i Do that?

```
    const imapConfig = {
          user: 'xxxx@icloud.com',
          password: 'xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx',
          host: 'imap.mail.me.com',
          port: 993,
          tls: true,
        };
    const imap = new Imap(imapConfig);
    function openInbox(cb) {
          imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);
        }
    
        imap.once('ready', () => {
          openInbox((err, box) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            const fetchOptions = {
              bodies: '',
              markSeen: false,
              struct: true,
            };
    
            const f = imap.seq.fetch('1:*', fetchOptions);
            f.on('message', (msg, seqno) => {
               console.log('Message #%d', seqno); })
```

I want to fetch messages in batches of 10 from latest to old

Answer (score 0):

IIRC openBox() returns an object that, among other things, contains the number of messages in the box. I can't remember the name of the field. I'm sure it wasn't x, but anyway, once you've found the name, all you need to do is call imap.seq.fetch for the range [x-10,x], with a bit of frippery in case x<11.